# How to add mp3 and to be played in an application?

Tags: java, android, audio, mp3

I tried a lot with my code below . there is no compile error at all. when I used to start the MP3 which I added , in the logcat window it shows "start called in state 0". please help me with this code . Thanks in advance .I also want to know when we pause the audio , i need to get the song resume from there when i click the start button  (or) Is there any resume function for it , Let me know in the comments section . Thanks in advance. Here's my Java code

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private MediaPlayer mp;
 

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
  Button mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
  Button mButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);

  mp = new MediaPlayer();

  mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    
    mp.start();
   }
  });
  mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    
    mp.stop();

   }
  });
  mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ch);
    mp.pause();

   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

create a class named AudioClip

```
public class AudioClip {
    public static boolean loop = false;
    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private static SoundPool soundPool;
    public static boolean isplayingAudio = false;
    public static void playAudio(Context c, int id) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, id);
        soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            isplayingAudio = true;
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(loop);
        }
    }
    public static void stopAudio() {
        isplayingAudio = false;
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

on other activity to play music

```
Context m = CuteActivity.this;
AudioClip.playAudio(m,  R.raw.ch);\
```

and to stop

```
            if (AudioClip.isplayingAudio) {
                    AudioClip.stopAudio();
                }
```